# Error in hive query Invalid table alias

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, amazon-dynamodb, hiveql

This is my hive query

```
  INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE bts_monthly_points_liability_rollforward
    SELECT currMonth.businessEventType,
        prevMonth.totalFaceValue,
        prevMonth.totalAccountingValue,
        currMonth.earnedFaceValue,
        currMonth.earnedAccountingValue,
        currMonth.expiredFaceValue,
        currMonth.expiredAccountingValue,
        currMonth.earnedPointsReturnFaceValue,
        currMonth.earnedPointsReturnAccountingValue,
        currMonth.spendPointsFaceValue,
        currMonth.spendPointsAccountingValue,
        currMonth.spendPointsReturnFaceValue,
        currMonth.spendPointsReturnAccountingValue,
        currMonth.adjustmentFaceValue,
        currMonth.adjustmentAccountingValue,
        currMonth.totalFaceValue,
        currMonth.totalAccountingValue
    FROM
    (
    SELECT business_event_type AS businessEventType,
        SUM(earned_face_value) AS earnedFaceValue,
        SUM(earned_accounting_value) AS earnedAccountingValue,
        SUM(expired_face_value) AS expiredFaceValue,
        SUM(expired_accounting_value) AS expiredAccountingValue,
        SUM(earned_return_face_value) AS earnedPointsReturnFaceValue,
        SUM(earned_return_accounting_value) AS earnedPointsReturnAccountingValue,
        SUM(spend_face_value) AS spendPointsFaceValue,
        SUM(spend_accounting_value) AS spendPointsAccountingValue,
        SUM(spend_return_face_value) AS spendPointsReturnFaceValue,
        SUM(spend_return_accounting_value) spendPointsReturnAccountingValue,
        CAST(0 AS BIGINT) AS adjustmentFaceValue,
        CAST(0 AS BIGINT) AS adjustmentAccountingValue,
        (SUM(earned_face_value)+SUM(expired_face_value)+SUM(earned_return_face_value)+SUM(spend_face_value)+SUM(spend_return_face_value)) AS totalFaceValue,
        (SUM(earned_accounting_value)+SUM(expired_accounting_value)+SUM(earned_return_accounting_value)+SUM(spend_accounting_value)+SUM(currMonth.spend_return_accounting_value)) AS totalAccountingValue
    FROM ${pointsApplicationName}_points_balance
    WHERE unix_timestamp(accounting_date,'yyyy-MM-dd') >= unix_timestamp("${startDate}",'yyyy-MM-dd') AND unix_timestamp(accounting_date,'yyyy-MM-dd') < unix_timestamp("${endDate}",'yyyy-MM-dd')
    GROUP BY business_event_type
    )currMonth
    JOIN 
    (
    SELECT business_event_type AS businessEventType,
        (SUM(earned_face_value)+SUM(expired_face_value)+SUM(earned_return_face_value)+SUM(spend_face_value)+SUM(spend_return_face_value)) AS totalFaceValue,
        (SUM(earned_accounting_value)+SUM(expired_accounting_value)+SUM(earned_return_accounting_value)+SUM(spend_accounting_value)+SUM(spend_return_accounting_value)) AS totalAccountingValue
    FROM ${pointsApplicationName}_points_balance 
    WHERE unix_timestamp(accounting_date,'yyyy-MM-dd') >= unix_timestamp("${previousMonthStartDate}",'yyyy-MM-dd') AND unix_timestamp(accounting_date,'yyyy-MM-dd') < unix_timestamp("${startDate}",'yyyy-MM-dd')
    GROUP BY business_event_type
    )prevMonth
    ON prevMonth.businessEventType = currMonth.businessEventType;
```

Error that I am receiving after running this query:

```
SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 38:129 Invalid table alias or column reference 'currMonth': (possible column names are: business_event_type, accounting_date, earned_face_value, earned_accounting_value, expired_face_value, expired_accounting_value, earned_return_face_value, earned_return_accounting_value, spend_face_value, spend_accounting_value, spend_return_face_value, spend_return_accounting_value)
Command exiting with ret '255'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the line 35 of your query. Here's how the query works:

```
SELECT ...
FROM (
    SELECT business_event_type AS businessEventType,
    ...
    (SUM(earned_accounting_value)+SUM(expired_accounting_value)+SUM(earned_return_accounting_value)+SUM(spend_accounting_value)+SUM(currMonth.spend_return_accounting_value)) AS totalAccountingValue
    FROM ${pointsApplicationName}_points_balance
    ...
)currMonth
JOIN (...)prevMonth
ON prevMonth.businessEventType = currMonth.businessEventType;
```

Here you can see that you are using currMonth alias inside of the subquery that aliased as currMonth. The alias does not exist in this context, this is why you get an error. It should be like this:

`(SUM(earned_accounting_value)+SUM(expired_accounting_value)+SUM(earned_return_accounting_value)+SUM(spend_accounting_value)+SUM(spend_return_accounting_value)) AS totalAccountingValue`